# How to apply a function of all elements of n Array?

Tags: scala

I'm a newbie in Scala and would like to apply a function (let's say `math.log`) on all elements of an Array[Double]. Th `foreach` doesn't work. What is the best way to do that?

Here is my code:

```
def func(arr: Array[Double]): Double = {

arr.map(a => log(a)).sum
}
```

Comment: do you mean you want to transform the elements in place?

Comment: that's possible. however creating a new variable is acceptable

Comment: `foreach()` is always tempting for newbies, but `map()` is where you want to start.

Comment: I actually tried map (arr.map (a=> log(a))), but it says type mismatch. I added my function in the original post

Comment: Can you post the signature of the `log` method?

Comment: I was making a bad mistaking and didn't put the math before the log. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scala> Array(1.1, 4.4, 9.9).map(math.log(_))
res21: Array[Double] = Array(0.09531017980432493, 1.4816045409242156, 2.2925347571405443)
```

Comment: Great one liner.  Can be even simpler with Array(...).map(math.log)

Comment: D'oh!!  I often forget about that reduction.  Thanks @Gangstead.